# My cookie class keeps returning null when getting the cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I am creating my own custom cookie class and I can not seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is my cookie class:

```
<?php
class Cookie implements CookieHandlerInterface {
  private $_domain;
  private $_secure;
  public function __construct(array $config = array()) {
    $this->_domain = isset($config['domain']) ? $config['domain'] : 'localhost';
    $this->_secure = isset($config['secure']) ? $config['secure'] : false;
  }
  public function set($name, $value = null, $timeLength) {
    if (!is_null($value)) {
      if (is_array($value)) {
        if ($this->__isMultiArray($array)) {
          return null;
        } else {
          $value = $this->__arrayBuild($value);
          $value = 'array(' . $value . ')';
        }
      } elseif (is_bool($value)) {
        if ($value) {
          $value = 'bool(true)';
        } else {
          $value = 'bool(false)';
        }
      } elseif (is_int($value)) {
        $value = 'int(' . strval($value) . ')';
      } elseif (is_float($value)) {
        $value = 'float(' . strval($value) . ')';
      } elseif (is_string($value)) {
        $value = 'string(' . $value . ')';
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } else {
      $value = 'null(null)';
    }
    setcookie($name, $value, (time() + $timeLength), '/', $this->_domain, $this->_secure, true);
  }
  public function get($name, $defualtOutput = null) {
    if (isset($_COOKIE[$name])) {
      $output = rtrim($_COOKIE[$name], ')');
      $xr1 = mb_substr($output, 0, 1);
      if (equals($xr1, 'a')) {
        $output = ltrim($output, 'array(');
        return $this->__arrayBreak($output);
      }
      if (equals($xr1, 'b')) {
        $output = ltrim($output, 'bool(');
        if (equals($output, 'true')) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
      if (equals($xr1, 'i')) {
        $output = ltrim($output, 'int(');
        return (int) $output;
      }
      if (equals($xr1, 'f')) {
        $output = ltrim($output, 'float(');
        return (float) $output;
      }
      if (equals($xr1, 's')) {
        $output = ltrim($output, 'string(');
        return $output;
      }
      if (equals($output, 'null(null)')) {
        return null;
      }
    }
    if (
      !is_array($defualtOutput)
      && !is_bool($defualtOutput)
      && !is_int($defualtOutput)
      && !is_float($defualtOutput)
      && !is_string($defualtOutput)
      && !is_null($defualtOutput)
    ) {
      trigger_error(
        'The $defualtOutput var needs to be only certain types of var types. Allowed (array, bool, int, float, string, null).',
        E_USER_ERROR
      );
    }
    return $defualtOutput;
  }
  public function delete($name) {
    if (isset($_COOKIE[$name])) {
        setcookie($name, '', time() - 3600, '/', $this->_domain, $this->_secure, true);
    }
  }
  private function __arrayBuild($array) {
    $out = '';
    foreach ($array as $index => $data) {
      $out .= ($data != '') ? $index . '=' . $data . '|' : '';
    }
    return rtrim($out, '|');
  }
  private function __arrayBreak($cookieString) {
    $array = explode('|', $cookieString);
    foreach ($array as $i => $stuff) {
        $stuff = explode('=', $stuff);
        $array[$stuff[0]] = $stuff[1];
        unset($array[$i]);
    }
    return $array;
  }
  private function __isMultiArray($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
      if (is_array($value)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
?>
```

I set a test cookie for example `app('cookie')->set('test', 'hello', 0);`
sure enough it created the cookie like expected. So the cookie reads `string(hello)`

When I try to echo it, it echos the default value instead of the actual variable, so `app('cookie')->get('test', 'test');` returns `test`

The get function should check if the cookie exists with `isset($_COOKIE[$cookieName])` and then it should trim the extra ) with `rtrim($_COOKIE[$cookieName], ')')` then it should grab the first character in the string with `mb_substr($_COOKIE[$cookieName], 0, 1)` the 0 starts at the beginning and the 1 grabs only the first character.

After it compares it with the default (a, b, i, f, s) for example if it starts with an `s` its a string by default, if it was `i` it was sent as an int by default, etc. etc.

If they all come up as false it checks to see if it was sent as null if so it return null else it returns the default value passed.

The equals function is the same as `$var1 == $var2` it is timing attack safe.

so it keeps returning the default value which is null, any help would be helpful thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol i feel real stupid i put 0 as the third argument thinking it will tell the cookie to expire when the browser session closes, but it did (time() + 0) which does not equal 0. so as it was setting the cookie it expired upon creation. So i did `time() - (time() * 2)`. i achieved the goal i wanted.